# How To Make Scroll In Unity Game?

Tags: popup, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game. I want a pop up Having 12 Buttons. When the Pop Up is appeared it has 6 GUI buttons and 6 buttons (down) in scroll. How Should I do that In Same Pop up with out NGUI Plugin?

Comment: There's no magic-trick, you'll have to manually code the logic yourself *(or use a GUI-library that does it for you)*

Answer (score 0):

I used this logic for that

```
if(Input.touchCount>0)
    {
        if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            dist=0f;
            tm=0f;
            speed=0f;
        }
        if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            scrollPosition.y+=Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y;
            dist+=Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y;
            tm+=Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            dist=0f;
            tm=0f;
        }
        if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if(tm>0)
                speed=dist*0.01f/tm;
            else
                speed=0f;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(speed>0)
        {
            speed-=moveValue;
        }
        else if(speed<0)
        {
            speed+=moveValue;
        }

        if(speed>-moveValue && speed<moveValue)
            speed=0f;

        scrollPosition.y+=speed;
    }
```

And inside OnGUI ()

```
scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView (new Rect (0f,150f,800f,480f),scrollPosition, new Rect (0f, 0f, 800f, 400f));
```

Use your own Rect coordinates. Also refer [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.BeginScrollView.html)